# Pycharm - how to change color for module/package name?

Tags: pycharm, syntax-highlighting

I try seeking for this in PyCharm and [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=pycharm+how+to+change+color+for+module+name&oq=pycharm+how+to+change+color+for+module+name&aqs=chrome..69i57.21909j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) though little helpful results found.

If you know how to, please share.

Comment: do u mean that there is a particular package name you want to to be of different color?

Comment: I mean any package/module name

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help, but my gut feeling for no support of it is that because once module is imported it is regarded as a regular variable, so I think there is no good way to distinguish module from the others.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > General,
in Text > Default Text > Foreground color picker box

Comment: This will change all text not the module/package name only.

Answer (score 0):

I use URxvt (Rxvt-unicode).  I have been searching for this for years!  I hope that someone finds it helpful!

I found that when I made the color choices for foreground and colorBD different, it would show the package a different color than the destription.  Here are the settings I used:

```
URxvt*colorBD: #fa8706
URxvt*foreground: #ffffff
```

This gave me an orange package name and a white package description.

There are also settings for colors for IT (Italics) and UL (Underline):

```
URxvt*colorIT: #87af5f
URxvt*colorBD: #fa8706
URxvt*colorUL: #87afd7
```